# background needs to have gradient

Tags: css

I am totally a noob to css and I have a need to add gradient to the background image on the top of the page.
here is what I tried but obviously its not working as background overwriting the value. How can I fix it

I have a background image and I need a gradient on top of it. Here is my css

```
body.test {
    /* Mozilla: */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00FF00, #000000);
    /* Chrome, Safari:*/
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
    left top, left bottom, from(#00FF00), to(#000000));
    /* MSIE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
        StartColorStr='#00FF00', EndColorStr='#000000', GradientType=0);
background: url(../mybackground.png);
}
```

**TEST HERE**
http://jsfiddle.net/PsDuF/

Comment: Your example is confusing. You have a large JPG image that already has a gradient. Are you trying to put another gradient on top of that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
background: url(../mybackground.png);
```

to

```
background-image:  url(../mybackground.png);
```

`background` is the shorthand syntax. Alternatively, you could combine the image with your other syntax:

```
background:  url(../mybackground.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00FF00, #000000);
```

In your case, you are declaring `background` multiple times, so each time you declare it, you are over-riding the previous declaration.

When you declare multiple background in one declaration, the order you declare them will change the stacking order. JSBIN example using images and mozilla background gradients: jsbin.com/abumuz/1

Note that if you want the gradient on top of the image, but still want to see the image, you need to make sure your gradient has alpha transparency.

Comment: background image sits ontop of the gradient now so I cant see gradient

Comment: What are you wanting it to do? If you want the gradient to show through the image then make sure it has transparency.

Comment: I want the gradiant to sit on top of the image

Comment: The gradient won't sit on top of an image. You need more elements to do that. Apply image to body... then gradient to element above body. But your gradient has 100% opacity, so it'll just cover any image.

Comment: @Scott you don't need multiple elements. You just change the order of the background declarations. Here's a JSBIN example with both the gradient on top, and then the image on top: http://jsbin.com/abumuz/1/

Comment: (note above linked example is for Mozilla. Add your webkit background as well as needed.)

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look at this [tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for creating CSS gradients.